# Translating "ok"

Tags: traducción

From what I have heard "es bien" could replace "it's ok" in Spanish. Is this right, or is there another word or phrase used as an "ok" after someone tells another person something

> Manuel, quiero ir a la playa.
>
> Bien

Would that make sense?

Comment: There is a video I've watched many times, which was translated into Spanish, and I watch it with the subtitles, and when the English is "Okay" sometimes the Spanish is "Okey" (pronounced the same, spelled differently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*es bien* doesn't actually replace *OK*, the one which does this is *está bien.*

*OK* could be translated in many ways, these are perfectly idiomatic for any circumstance:

> De acuerdo.
>   Está bien.
>   Bien.
>   Ningún problema.
>   Me parece.
>   Ya.
>   OK (worldwide used)

Comment: ¡El español tiene tantas opciones!  Vamos, dale, vale, como no, venga, conformo … … …

Comment: In Spanish you can also use the work "ok", but usually the most common and informal translation,in Spain, is "vale"

Comment: In Chile the most common and transversal is "ya". Of course we say also "okey" and its derivatives "oca" (casual and frequent) and "ocalecuá" (obsolete). Hardly we used "vale", but is becoming more common.

Comment: @Rodrigo Olvidé ese!

Comment: And don't forget "ok"

Comment: And Arnold says: "No Problemo"

Answer (score 1):

Ok is not a word in Spanish. However, there are many different ways to substitute ok, but here are the most simple ways to say ok.

- Esta bien [it's okay]
- Estas/ esta bien? [are you okay]
- Si [yes]
  Use si when you are answering a question. For example ,"Quieres ir al parque?" You would answer [normally] with," Si. Quiero ir al parque." Not with ok like in English.
- Bien